# Different blocks on the same page, dependent on source link?

Tags: blocks, uri

Is it possible to have a page that shows (e.g.) one of three different blocks, depending on the originating page link? I'm thinking the only way to achieve this would be to use # or something similar at the end of the URL.

Example:

```
link one: mysite.com/mypage#one
link two: mysite.com/mypage#two
link three: mysite.com/mypage#three
```

And then create the three blocks, with the visibility settings set appropriately.

Is this a robust solution that would work with URL aliases etc.?

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do it programmatically you can always parse url and display different content for different anchor or other param. You can always use one block for display content according to conditions.

Take a look to Context or Rules modules, maybe you find easier solution